# iOS/Xcode: Cannot find recurrent events with predicateForEventsWithStartDate and startDate and endDate outside my search range

Tags: ios, xcode, ekevent

In iOS events are stored by their startDate and endDate and their recurrence rules.
If i want to fetch all events for the next 3 days i only get events with the start date within the next three days.
BUT: i do not get events, which are recurring and their startDate is not within my search range, i suppose the reason is that the iOS Calendar is computing on the fly all days when the event occurs, but does not use this information when searching programmaticaly in the EKEventStore.

So ist there a way to find recurring events within my "search date frame" when their startDate is outside the range and some recurrence rules are applied?

best regards,
Christian

```
NSDate *date_today = [self dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *endDate = [self dateByAddingDays:3 toDate:date_today];

NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:date_today
                                          endDate:endDate calendars:nil];
NSArray *events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:searchPredicate];
```

Comment: can you post your predicate method, predicateForEventsWithStartDate ? It sounds like you want to add an OR condition using whatever attributes are involved in "recurrence" maybe?